# Access denied to Business Data Connectivity

Tags: 2013, bdc

User is trying to create external content types using SQL Server, using sharepoint designer. I as an SharePoint Administrator i can login without any issue but this user who is dbo of remote sql server and is a site owner of the sharepoint site cant add connection is prompted with this error.

[image]

Have anyone experienced such issue in past, please share your experiences.

Thank You

Comment: are you an administrator of the BDC Service Application?

Comment: I am part of SharePoint farm Admin group, so i believe i have admin privilieges over the BDC application too.

Comment: go to Manage Service Applications -> Business Data Catalog Service , put a check mark next to your ECT and click Set Object Permissions, and give your users like "Execute" & "Selectable in Client"

Comment: I just found out for user to have ability to add connection user needs to have Edit permission in Metadata Store Permissions. But Edit is so highly privileged permissions, it displays all the BDC connection made by other users and gived users ability to modify them. Is there a better way to manage the users permissions, Still allow user to add connection not not have ability to edit others?

Answer (score 0):

The user in question needs to be granted access to the BDC application.  In Central Administration access BDC service, select the BDC application and then grant the user the expected permissions.

Comment: But i cant even add the BDC application because we get that error message.

Comment: You get the error in SharePoint Designer.  You need to set permission in Central Administration.

Comment: I just found out for user to have ability to add connection user needs to have Edit permission in Metadata Store Permissions. But Edit is so highly privileged permissions, it displays all the BDC connection made by other users and gived users ability to modify them. Is there a better way to manage the users permissions, Still allow user to add connection not not have ability to edit others?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Central Administration > Application Management > Manage
   service applications > Click Business Data Connectivity Service,
2. Select the created External Content Type and click Set Object
   Permissions.
3. Click Add and give the Object Permission to All Users (windows), and
   select the Level of Permissions to be given to them below and click
   OK.
4. Select the created External Content Type and click Set Metadata
   Store Permissions.
5. Click Add and give the Metadata Store Permissions to All Users
   (windows), and select the Level of Permissions to be given to them
   below and click OK.

source: https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-bdc-configuration-and-creating-external-content-type-and-external-list-part-two/